# apache kerberos authentication tickets are not visible under klist

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-14.04, mitkerberos, pam-krb

when i configured the apache authentication using the kerberos. it is working fine. It is asking the password and logging into the website. and it is creating a log information like this. 
**/var/log/kerberos/krb5kdc.log**

```
Jul 03 15:30:03 ashokkrishna-Lenovo-B560 krb5kdc[4060](info): AS_REQ (6 etypes {18 17 16 23 25 26}) 192.168.1.224: NEEDED_PREAUTH: ashokkrishna@IGROUP.COM for krbtgt/IGROUP.COM@IGROUP.COM, Additional pre-authentication required
Jul 03 15:30:03 ashokkrishna-Lenovo-B560 krb5kdc[4060](info): AS_REQ (6 etypes {18 17 16 23 25 26}) 192.168.1.224: ISSUE: authtime 1435917603, etypes {rep=18 tkt=18 ses=18}, ashokkrishna@IGROUP.COM for krbtgt/IGROUP.COM@IGROUP.COM
```

but when i hit

```
ashokkrishna@ashokkrishna-Lenovo-B560:~$ klist
klist: No credentials cache found (ticket cache FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)
```

It is not listing any obtained tickets. why?
everytime when i open the firefox the website is asking the password and username again and again, although my ticket expiration time is long enough.

but when i adding the users using

```
ashokkrishna@ashokkrishna-Lenovo-B560:~$ kinit ashokkrishna
Password for ashokkrishna@IGROUP.COM: 

ashokkrishna@ashokkrishna-Lenovo-B560:~$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000
Default principal: ashokkrishna@IGROUP.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
2015-07-03T15:56:33  2015-07-04T01:56:33  krbtgt/IGROUP.COM@IGROUP.COM
    renew until 2015-07-04T15:56:30
2015-07-03T15:56:44  2015-07-04T01:56:33  HTTP/igroup.com@IGROUP.COM
    renew until 2015-07-04T15:56:30
```

its working fine.

why this is happening.

**EDIT:**
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sites-enabled.
**

```
<Directory /var/www/html/auth-kerberos>
    AuthType Kerberos
    AuthName "Kerberos Authntication"
    KrbAuthRealms IGROUP.COM
    Krb5Keytab /etc/krb5.keytab
    KrbMethodNegotiate On
    KrbSaveCredentials Off
    KrbVerifyKDC Off
    Require valid-user
</Directory>**
```

kadmin.local configuration.

```
kadmin.local: listprincs
HTTP/igroup.com@IGROUP.COM
K/M@IGROUP.COM
ashokkrishna/admin@IGROUP.COM
ashokkrishna@IGROUP.COM
host/igroup.com@IGROUP.COM
kadmin/admin@IGROUP.COM
kadmin/changepw@IGROUP.COM
kadmin/igroup.com@IGROUP.COM
krbtgt/IGROUP.COM@IGROUP.COM
root/admin@IGROUP.COM
```

ashokkrishna is the user(client).And one thing i am having kdc,admin-server,apache-server,client all are under single host(pc). I am testing in single system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `KrbMethodNegotiate` fails because you don't have a valid (in your case any) ticket, Apache fails back to `KrbMethodK5Passwd`, which is on by default. 
**This is the expected behavior** with your configuration.

---

Side notes

1. Apache shouldn't be using the system keytab. Configure an application keytab for it.
2. > If you are using the Basic Auth mechanism, the module does not do any special
   >   encryption of any sort. The passing of the username and password is done with
   >   the same Base64 encoding that Basic Auth uses. This can easily be converted to
   >   plain text. To counter this, I would suggest also using mod_ssl or Apache-SSL.
   >   The use of SSL encryption is also recommended if you are using the Negotiate
   >   method.

Comment: ok i understood it i put the configuration KrbMethodK5Passwd Off  it is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

> *[Kerberos authentication]* is working fine. It is asking the password and logging into the website.

Your Apache server is probably configured to allow some form of fall-back authentication when no Kerberos authentication can be negotiated.
Because if your browser had presented a Kerberos ticket you would **not** have been prompted for a username and password.

To me that is confirmed by the fact you see neither your personal ticket granting ticket, nor a service ticket.

Once you manually obtain a ticket granting ticket with `kinit`, only then Firefox is able and willing negotiate Kerberos authentication with the webserver, and then the service ticket is used to log in, rather than username/password. Which is what show when you run `klist` the second time.

Comment: no, as per my knowledge i configured everything correctly. see the updated configuration in the question

Comment: ok actually as you said when i opened the site without prior kinit(getting tickets). I got internal server error and i cannot able to get the page. But after i changed the permission of krb5.keytab file to chmod 777 krb5.keytab. from that time onwards the firefox is asking me the username and passwords.